# Dimensional Charting with Non-Exclusive Attributes

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

The following is a schematic, simplified, table, showing HTTP transactions. I'd like to build a DC analysis for it using `dc`, but some of the columns don't map well to `crossfilter`.

[image: Schematic HTTP Transactions]

In the settings of this question, all HTTP transactions have the fields `time`, `host`, `requestHeaders`, `responseHeaders`, and `numBytes`. However, different transactions have different specific HTTP request and response headers. In the table above, 0 and 1 represent the absence and presence, respectively, of a specific header in a specific transaction. The sub-columns of `requestHeaders` and `responseHeaders` represent the unions of the headers present in transactions. Different HTTP transaction datasets will almost surely generate different sub-columns.

For this question, a row in this chart is represented in code like this:

```
{
    "time": 0,
    "host": "a.com",
    "requestHeaders": {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "baz": 1},
    "responseHeaders": {"shmip": 0, "shmap": 1, "shmoop": 0},
    "numBytes": 12
}
```

The `time`, `host`, and `numBytes` all translate easily into `crossfilter`, and so it's possible to build charts answering things like what was the total number of bytes seen for transactions between 2 and 4 for host `a.com`. E.g.,

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
...
var hostDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.host;
});
var hostBytes = hostDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.numBytes;
});
```

The problem is that, for all slices of `time` and `host`, I'd like to show (capped) bar charts of the (leading) request and response headers by bytes. E.g. (see the first row), for time 0 and host `a.com`, the request headers bar chart should show that `bar` and `baz` each have 12.

There are two problems, a minor one and a major one.

**Minor Problem**

This doesn't fit quite naturally into `dc`, as it's one-directional. These bar charts should be updated for the other slices, but they can't be used for slicing themselves. E.g., you shouldn't be able to select `bar` and deselect `baz`, and look for a resulting breakdown of hosts by bytes, because what would this mean: hosts in the transactions that have `bar` but don't have `baz`? hosts in the the transactions that have `bar` and either do or don't have `baz`? It's too unintuitive.

How can I make some `dc` charts one directional. Is it through some hack of disabling mouse inputs?

**Major Problem**

As opposed to `host`, `foo` and `bar` are non-exclusive. Each transaction's host is either something or the other, but a transaction's headers might include any combination of `foo` and `bar`.

How can I define crossfilter dimensions for `requestHeaders`, then, and how can I use `dc`? That is

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
...
var requestHeadersDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    // What should go here? 
});
```

Comment: The way I usually deal with the major problem you state is to transform my data so that there is a separate record for each header (all other fields in these duplicate records are the same). Then I use custom group aggregations to avoid double-counting. These custom aggregations are a bit hard to manage so I built Reductio to help with this using the 'exception' function - https://github.com/esjewett/reductio

Comment: Thanks, @Ethan Jewett! I've encountered Reductio before, and it seemed very good. Will read up more about the ``exception`` function. If I may say so, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Ethan Jewett I've ended up going a different way, because in the real-life scenario, each row, in a dataset that is to begin with quite large, would end up being multiplied dozens of times (that's the multiplicity of request headers in the relevant HTTP requests). It would not have been efficient. I still think that ``Reductio`` is an excellent library (just for other settings), and would be happy if you'd post your comment above as an answer.

Comment: Cool solution :-) I will post it as an answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacked it (efficiently, but very inelegantly) by looking at the source code of `dc`. It's possible to distort the meaning of `crossfilter` to achieve the desired effect.

The final result is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atavory/0dpgjsda/2/). It is slightly more limited than the question, as the fields of `responseHeaders` are hardcoded to `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. Removing this restriction is more in the domain of simple Javascript.

**Minor Problem**

Using a [simple css hack](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/), I simply defined

```
.avoid-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and gave the div this class. Inelegant but effective.

**Major Problem**

The major problem is solved by distorting the meaning of `crossfilter` concepts, and "fooling" `dc`.

Let's say the data looks like this:

```
var transactions = [
  {
      "time": 0,
      "host": "a.com",
      "requestHeaders": {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "baz": 1},
      "responseHeaders": {"shmip": 0, "shmap": 1, "shmoop": 0},
      "numBytes": 12
  },
  {
      "time": 1,
      "host": "b.org",
      "requestHeaders": {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "baz": 1},
      "responseHeaders": {"shmip": 0, "shmap": 1, "shmoop": 1},
      "numBytes": 3
  },
  ...
];
```

We can define a "dummy" dimension, which ignores the data:

```
var transactionsNdx = crossfilter(transactions);

var dummyDim = transactionsNdx
  .dimension(function(d) {
    return 0;
  });
```

Using this dimension, we can define a group that counts the total `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` bytes of the filtered rows:

```
var requestHeadersGroup = dummyDim
  .group()
  .reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
      return {
        "foo": p.foo + v.requestHeaders.foo * v.numBytes,
        "bar": p.bar + v.requestHeaders.bar * v.numBytes,
        "baz": p.baz + v.requestHeaders.baz * v.numBytes,
      }
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
      return {
        "foo": p.foo - v.requestHeaders.foo * v.numBytes,
        "bar": p.bar - v.requestHeaders.bar * v.numBytes,
        "baz": p.baz - v.requestHeaders.baz * v.numBytes,
      }
    },
    /* initialize p */
    function () {
      return {
        "foo": 0,
        "bar": 0,
        "baz": 0
      }
    }
  );
```

Note that this isn't a proper `crossfilter` group at all. It will not map the dimensions to their values. Rather, it maps 0 to a value which itself maps the dimensions to their values (ugly!). We therefore need to transform this group into something that actually looks like a `crossfilter` group:

```
var getSortedFromGroup = function() {
  var all = requestHeadersGroup.all()[0].value;
  all = [
    {
      "key": "foo",
      "value": all.foo
    },
    {
      "key": "bar",
      "value": all.bar
    },
    {
      "key": "foo",
      "value": all.baz
    }];
  return all.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs.value - rhs.value;
  });
}
var requestHeadersDisplayGroup = {
  "top": function(k) {
      return getSortedFromGroup();
    },
  "all": function() {
      return getSortedFromGroup();
    },
};
```

We now can create a regular `dc` chart, and pass the adaptor group
`requestHeadersDisplayGroup` to it. It works normally from this point on.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually deal with the major problem you state is to transform my data so that there is a separate record for each header (all other fields in these duplicate records are the same). Then I use custom group aggregations to avoid double-counting. These custom aggregations are a bit hard to manage so I built Reductio to help with this using the 'exception' function - github.com/esjewett/reductio